# What does Apple mean by telling about 64bit requirement for extensions on iOS8?

Tags: ios, ios8, cpu-architecture, arm64

What does apple really want to say with the **bold** sentence?

For example, I have 3rd party libs in my application which are not compiled as 64bit, but I do not use any of them inside the extension. Should I "still" compile 3rd party libraries of the containing app (my main app that includes the extension) for 64bit architecture? (I don't want to do that as it is very hard also it will double the size of my app as I don't even target armv7s but just armv7)

> Note about 64-bit architecture
>
> An app extension target must include the arm64 (iOS) or x86_64
>   architecture (OS X) in its Architectures build settings or it will be
>   rejected by the App Store. Xcode includes the appropriate 64-bit
>   architecture with its “Standard architectures” setting when you create
>   a new app extension target.
>
> **If your containing app target links to an embedded framework, the app
>   must also include 64-bit architecture or it will be rejected by the
>   App Store.**
>
> For more information about 64-bit development, see 64-Bit Transition
>   Guide for Cocoa Touch or 64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa, depending
>   on your target platform.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your extension must have a 64-bit version. That means that if you use framework you must include a 64-bit version.

If the code is used only in the main app and not the extension then it doesn't need to be 64-bit.

Having said that, it's been over a year since the first 64-bit iOS devices became available. Even if you can't build fully arm64 right now you should probably have a plan to migrate.

Comment: It can contain 32 bit code. It must also contain 64 bit.

Comment: Good point -- that's what I meant but not what I wrote. I clarified my answer slightly.

Comment: @quellish You say that for the extension right? Not the containing app.

Comment: Second paragraph of my answer. (Yes.)

Comment: @frankish, both. 32 bit applications can only load 32 bit frameworks, and 64 bit applications can only load 64 bit frameworks. Including a 64 bit framework with a 32 bit application would not make sense.

Comment: @quellish As far as I understand, container app does not load the extension. It requests from the operating system and operating system runs it in another process. So last comment of the StephenDarlington contradicts with your comment. I hope that I interpret your sentences incorrectly, otherwise I won't be able to add a basic extension to my armv7 app. (I tested it and it works technically without any problem. But will Apple reject it? That is my concern :|)

Comment: No, I think @quellish is saying exactly the same thing I am. The extension needs to be both 64- and 32-bit. The app can be only 32-bit if you want.

Comment: I checked this answer by submitting the app. Application was 32-bit. extension was both 32 and 64bit. It is approved every single time I submitted an update. This proves that this answer is 100% correct.